# How to take a UIViewController out of a series of NavigationControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to segue from a `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController`. Currently, I have a segue in place but this forces the second `UIViewController` to inherit the `UINavigationController` characteristics, which I don't want. Is there a way to tell the second `UIViewController` to not inherit these characteristics?

Comment: Do you want to *show* another view controller, and then be able to return to the navigation controller? Or do you want to *replace* the navigation controller?

Comment: I want to show another view controller and then be able to return @DonMag

Comment: Unclear what "inherit the characteristics" means. So we don't know what it is that you don't want this view controller to do. It sounds like maybe you want a Present Modally segue instead of a Show segue. But it's hard to tell.

Comment: @helloworld12345 - you want to look at **presenting** a view controller. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present or, if you are using a Storyboard segue, look at `Present Modally`

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```